# What authentication methods are supported by Excel's "Data Feed" data source?

Tags: microsoft-excel, authentication

In Excel 2016, I'm adding a data source using "From OData Data Feed". The Data Connection Wizard appears and asks for the OData URL and optionally authentication credentials.

If I provide a username and password, what authentication methods does this support? Will it use HTTP basic authentication? Does it only support Kerberos? I'm unable to find any documentation that describes what authentication methods are supported.

[image: Data Connection Wizard]

Answer (score 1):

I would love to find documentation that lists all the possibilities. But, through testing, I've found this wizard makes two requests:

- The first request is unauthenticated.
- If the first request return 401 Unauthorized, it uses the `WWW-Authenticate` response header to make a second request with credentials.

It does support HTTP basic authentication.

The "Use the sign-in information for the person opening this file" option seems to imply it will also do Kerberos authentication.